# ping can resolve hostname, while dig is unable to resolve the same hostname?

Tags: debian, dns, cloud, kubernetes, dig

> ping can resolve hostname, while dig is unable to resolve the same hostname?

I'm experiencing a strange issue, where `ping` is able to resolve some DNS hostname, while `dig` cannot.

I've tried to `dig +search` to use the search entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`, or `dig @<nameserver>` to set the nameserver explicitly, but that didn't help.

How can I understand why `ping` resolves the hostnames, while `dig` is unable?

```
kube@ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 100.64.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local eu-central-1.compute.internal
options ndots:5
kube@ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl:~$ dig +search ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1-Debian <<>> +search ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 52708
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl. IN    A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 100.64.0.10#53(100.64.0.10)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 23 14:46:46 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60

kube@ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl:~$ dig @100.64.0.10 +search ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1-Debian <<>> @100.64.0.10 +search ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 47568
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl. IN    A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 100.64.0.10#53(100.64.0.10)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 23 14:46:53 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60

kube@ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl:~$ ping ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl
PING ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl (100.96.1.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl (100.96.1.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl (100.96.1.8): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl (100.96.1.8): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
^C
--- ctf-k8s-deploy-647d66b697-lxqkl ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 40ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.019/0.019/0.021/0.005 ms
```

**Update**:

`/etc/hosts`:

```
kube@ctf1-deploy1-89b48b46-zkqld:~$ cat /etc/hosts
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
100.96.3.22     ctf1-deploy1-89b48b46-zkqld
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
kube@ctf1-deploy1-89b48b46-zkqld:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 100.64.0.10
search ctf1-ns.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local eu-central-1.compute.internal
options ndots:5
```

Answer (score 1):

Ping and dig use different mechanism to resolve IP addresses. 
While `ping` gets configuration from the line which is seems like `hosts: files dns` in /etc/nsswitch.conf file and `dig` uses the name server configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` because dig queries only DNS Server. 
So your problem can be an issue about DNS Servers which are define in /etc/hosts file.

[There is another clarification](https://www.putorius.net/why-does-ping-and-dns-resolve-names.html)

Comment: Thank you @Ozerov. In my case `/etc/nsswith.conf` doesn't exist, but `/etc/nsswitch.conf` does. Furthermore, there is no nameserver in `/etc/hosts`, but only in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Can you say what `hosts: files dns` means?

Comment: my bad,I have edited name it is just `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. `files` point to the use of `/etc/hosts` and `dns` means the use of Domain Name Service. if `files` comes first, it means that system will try to find ip address in `/etc/hosts` file. If `dns` comes first then domain lookup will consult DNS before any other services or files.
Can you provide an output of `cat /etc/hosts` ?

Comment: I've added `/etc/hosts`. Are you sure, you are not confusing `/etc/hosts` with `/etc/resolv.conf`, where the DNS server is listed?

Comment: Sorry again, dig checks the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. And the problem must be in your ``/etc/resolv.conf`` file because `search ...` line should be defined first and ```nameserver 100.64.0.10``` should be defined after that. Can you try it?